# open files which stored in database using default android program

Tags: android, database

i want to open files in database using default android program...but i have a trouble in opening it...
i store the files path in my database (as string), because it is better to store the files path instead of the files it self...(from what i read)
but when i want to open it in android using the default android program, it goes nothing...just blank...
i don't know which part i wrong, because the log cat didn't show anything...
here is my code...

```
String fileId = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.fileid)).getText().toString();
String fileName = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TextView01)).getText().toString();
String filePath = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.filepath)).getText().toString();

//starting activity intent
Intent intent= new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

File file = new File("http://10.0.2.2/" + filePath);

MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String ext = file.getName().substring(file.getName().indexOf(".")+1).toLowerCase();
String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);

try
{
    startActivity(intent);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
{
    Toast.makeText(FileChooser.this, "No Application available to View this file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

the filePath is android/untitled.jpg
actually i'm really new in developing android...i hope anyone can help me solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

i got it...
finally i finished it with my own...
if one of you guys confuse about the same thing with me...hope this will help...

```
    public void clearCache() 
    {
        fileCache.clear();
    }

    private File getFileFromUrl(String url)
    {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);
        try
        {
            URL docUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)docUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            return f;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String GetExtention(String name)
    {
        name = name.replaceAll("%20", " ");
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String type = name;
        String filenameArray[] = type.split("\\.");
        type = filenameArray[filenameArray.length-1];
        String ext = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(type.toLowerCase());
        return ext;
    }
```

while the file cache is class you make...
for more help [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/) can help you...